# Linode Exporter in Opentelemetry Collector

Tags: logging, yaml, open-telemetry, linode, exporter

Is there a Linode Exporter that i can use in the opentelemetry collector?. I want to use it to export logs into Linode Object storage.

I tried  configuring the exporter in the configuration file as follows:

```
exporters:
  linode:
    access_key: "<my-access-key>"
    secret_key: "<my-secret-key>"
    bucket_name: "logs-store"
    object_key_prefix: "logs/"
    endpoint: "http://logs-store.ap-south-1.linodeobjects.com"
```

But when i deploy the collector on a kubernetes cluster, the pod goes into `CrashLoopBackOff` state. I then checked the logs for the collector pod, It states that linode isn't a valid exporter.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no such [exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter) but you could keep an eye on the [S3 exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/2835) that you should be able to use, given the S3 compatibility.